# ember.js and x-vlc-plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js, vlc

I'm trying to embed *x-vlc-plugin* into my *ember.js* code.

HTML:

```
template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(
*/
* VLC Player Audio Tag
*/
'<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" '+
        'id="audioX" '+
        'autoplay="no" '+
        'loop="no" '+
        'volume="100" '+
        'target="test.mp3">'
)
```

Controller:

```
player2: null,
playMusic: function()
{
    this.set('player2', $('#audioX')[0]);
    this.player2.playlist.play();
},
```

Error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined**

Why, if simple HTML page (witohut *ember.js*) works fine?

```
<html>
<head><title>test</title></head>
<body>
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
         name="video1"
         id="audioX"
         autoplay="no" loop="yes" width="400" height="300"
         target="test.mp3" />  
<script>
  var vlc = document.getElementById("audioX");
  vlc.playlist.play();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In controllers, you must refer to properties using `get` and `set`:

```
this.player2.playlist.play();
```

should be:

```
this.get('player2').playlist.play();
```

Comment: I still see the same error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined".

Comment: Use the debugger and see what is stored in the `player2` property-  You set `player2` in the `playMusic` function, but I don't see you calling it

Comment: Object 'playlist' and it's method play() are not visible in debugger both in ember and html+js example. However html+js example is able to play mp3.